# Auth0 Login endpoint not showing the login form

Tags: authentication, next.js, auth0

Auth0 Login endpoint not working, just redirecting

## Auth0 Login endpoint not working.

Whenever I type in http://example.com/api/auth/login, login form does not show up. It instead redirects me to https://example.com. I tried clearing cookies and using a different browser but to no avail. I set the callback correctly in the website as well.

**Expected result:**
The form shows up
**Actual result:**
Redirects me to home page of site.

Using next.js and vercel.